# Historical and future dividends

Tags: stocks, dividends

Do any of you know where I can find the history of dividends paid by a company in the United States and the next date they will pay?

Comment: It is worth noting that historical dividends may be raw (as declared) or adjusted for corporate events such as stock splits, spinoffs etc.

Comment: An alternative for requesting data is [OpenData.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like this site:
[A site with dividend history](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/xom/dividend-history)

However, they only give future dividends if the dividend has been declared.